# Play different audios in different time periods in android

Tags: java, android, time

I'm new to android development. I tried to get the touch time duration and play an audio on at different time periods. I did the following code.

```
private long pressTime;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        pressTime = android.os.SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() 
                - event.getDownTime();          
        if (pressTime > 5000) {             
            Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, "5 Sec", 5);
            t.show();
        }else if (pressTime > 20000 && pressTime < 30000){
            Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, "20 Sec", 5);
            t.show();
        }
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

I need the first touch action in 5 seconds. But in this code, toast is not working. I got this example from stack overflow. How can I play an audio(or show a toast) in different time periods?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to handle action down and action up.  On action down, you save the current time.  On action up, you compare this time to the time saved in the down, and display the appropriate toast (or play the appropriate sound).

Comment: What's not working? Please update your code with what you tried. "It's not working" isn't helpful to people trying to help you, which in turn isn't helpful to you.

Comment: @Override
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
  int eventaction = event.getAction();
  switch (eventaction) {
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
   pressTime = event.getEventTime() - event.getDownTime();
   System.out.println(pressTime);
   break;
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
   if (pressTime > 2000) {
    Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, "2 sec", 5);
    t.show();
   }
   break;
  }
  return true;
 }